# Images are different size

Tags: html, css, image

I was putting chess pieces(pawns,images) on my"custom" made chess board, i used 100px image, so i put changed the size to 50px instead and aligned to center. When i did the same with white pawns i noticed that black pawns are noticible bigger than white pawns.

Code(HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
        <title>Chess</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table  border="1">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
            </tr>

            <!--Added Black Pawns-->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="blck_pawn.png" alt="Black Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
            </tr>
            <!--Added Black pawns-->

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
                <td bgcolor="black"> <img src="wht_pawn.png" alt="White Pawn" height="50" width="50" align= center> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td bgcolor="black"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS(example.css):

```
table {
    background-color:none;
    }
td {

    background-color:none;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Images downloaded from: https://opengameart.org/content/chess-pieces-and-board-squares
- PNGs, NoShadow, 1x,--> b_pawn, w_pawn

How it looks like: https://pasteboard.co/IW24oTG.png

Comment: try adding `td img { width: 100% }` to your CSS. The larger images need to be able to stretch/shrink. Also try and remove the `width` and `height` from the `<img>` tags, they are redundant and are handled by your CSS...

Comment: Next step would be adding `img { display: block }` (default is `ìnline-block`) to your CSS to remove unwanted space below your images....

Comment: Thanks for your help, first one made black pieces stretched (same to fields under), second one didnt change anything to white pieces (space around image).

Comment: Just remember the second one as I am sure you will encounter the problem one page or another.

Comment: Oh, i noticed images have different size..

Comment: Off-Topic: you could use svg images instead of pngs

Comment: I thought png is better... well thats because i didnt know what "svg" stands for, ty

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code using the images you provided under

> JonPablok Cburnett Chess Set/PNGs/No shadow/1x

and was unable to reproduce your problem. It looks like maybe your source images start at a different size? If so, there could be more white space around one of them. Try using the images unaltered.

[image: My result using your code and unaltered images]

Comment: Thanks, i think i might have stretch black pawn by resizing them nor the table...